# How to Use QML StackView?

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2, qt-quick, qtquickcontrols

I am a beginner in QMl and have worked more on StackWidget in QT C++.In QML  i am confused to use **stackView** and have written following code:

```
Window {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Stack view")

    MainForm {
        StackView {
            id: stackView
            x: 0
            y: 0
            width: 360
            height: 360

            initialItem: page1

            Rectangle {
                id: page1

                //anchors.fill: parent
                color: "lightgreen"
                Button {
                    id: buttonPage1
                    text: "back to 2"
                    anchors.centerIn: parent
                    onClicked: {
                        stackView.pop()  //**Is THIS CORRECT**
                        stackView.push(page2) //**Is THIS CORRECT**

                    }
                }
                TextEdit {
                    id: te1
                    width: 105
                    height: 40
                    text: "enter"
                }
            }
            Rectangle {
                id: page2

                //anchors.fill: parent
                color: "lightblue"
                Button {
                    id: buttonPage2
                    text: "back to 1"
                    anchors.centerIn: parent
                    onClicked: {
                        stackView.pop() //**Is THIS CORRECT**
                    }
                }
                TextEdit {
                    id: te2
                    width: 109
                    height: 29
                    text: "enter"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Below are the questions:**

1. In StackWidget i was using setCurrentIndex to set the desired page and I know that in QML i should use push and pop. In that case how to use push and pop to navigate between **page1** and **page2** based on some selection. ?
2. Initially, can I load all the pages to the **stackView**?
3. How to save the content in the page when I pop an item from stackView?

Comment: It sounds like you want [StackLayout](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-layouts-stacklayout.html) instead of StackView.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I know that I will not exactly answer your question on how to use the `StackView`, that is because I think you don't want to have a `StackView` following your description.

The use-case of a `StackView` is, when you have the pages - as the names suggests - on a stack. If you only want to switch between pages, where it is not determinable, which one is logically below another, the `StackView` is not what you want, and you might want to consider a `SwipeView`.

In the `SwipeView` the pages coexist in a side-by-side manner. Since Qt 5.9 they have a `interactive` property with which you might disable the *swipe behaviour*.
Here you can choose the page you want to show by setting the `currentIndex`.

However, the `SwipeView` will create its pages as needed, to reduce the memory and CPU load (effectively disabling bindings of unloaded pages). This might result in data loss, if the data is not stored in a `model` outside the page itself.

If you want to have all the pages loaded at the same time, and you only want to switch the visible one, you might go with a simple custom component:

```
Item {
    property int currentIndex
    Page1 { visible: parent.currentIndex === 0 }
    Page2 { visible: parent.currentIndex === 1 }
    Page3 { visible: parent.currentIndex === 2 }
    ...
}
```

Or you go like:

MyView.qml

```
Item {
    id: root
    property int currentIndex: 0
    default property Item newContent

    onNewContentChanged: {
        newContent.parent = root
        newContent.visible = Qt.binding(bindingsClosure(root.children.length - 1))
    }

    function bindingsClosure(index) { return function() { return root.currentIndex === index } }
}
```

main.qml

```
MyView {
    Page1 { }
    Page2 { }
    Page3 { }
}
```

Comment: Your above answer almost matches my requirement and i will try swipeView and then will mark it has answer.